# Facebook Like button stopped working suddenly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

My fancy OpenGraph Facebook like button for my quotation mashup suddenly decided to stop working. It now says I provide an invalid url. The url is basically quotation?q=123 with 123 being the currently displayed quotation. They are usually generated randomly when someone arrives at the page.

All was fine, now it seems to be implying I can't have URLs like this, must I encode them? Or that I have meta tags that OpenGraph needs wrong or in the wrong place. It was odd that it suddenly started working, even the example [from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) is showing the error:

Invalid URL
 The requested URL "/plugins/like.php?

Did Facebook break?

I used some development tool they provide to get more info, which seems to baffle me even more as my meta tags are inside the head tag.

[Debugging info from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=%3Cdiv%20class=%22fb-like%22%20data-href=%22http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/favouriteQuotationsMashup.php?q=216%22%20data-send=%22true%22%20data-width=%22500%22%20data-show-faces=%22false%22%3E%3C/div%3E)

Ideas, just wait to see if Facebook fixes itself?

Comment: The first time I load the URL [link](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/favouriteQuotationsMashup.php) it seems to work but reloading the page and showing a second random quotation seems to then break the like button. If that makes sense?

Comment: The link you provide works for me (did about 4 refreshes -> like). Could you explain what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Instead of a like button the text "Invalid URL" was shown in its place. I think something was wrong with Facebook as their own example I linked to was showing the same error. Now everything seems to be working as it did before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must have been wrong with the mothership, as a day later give or take a few hours, my webpage (app) with the fanciest like button is working as expected again.

[Quotation Mashup](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/favouriteQuotationsMashup.php)